# I need help clicking login using Autohotkey

Tags: dom, com, autohotkey

i am trying to automate the log in to my company website that launches one of the programs i need on a daily basis, but i cant find a way of getting the page to login,

i have tried so many different thing it would be impossible to list them all, but some include,

```
wb.document.getElementById("login").Click
wb.document.getElementById("OraButton left").Click
wb.document.getElementByClassName("OraButton left").Click
```

This is my code that is working fine,

```
wb := IEGet("Login") ;Tab name you define can also be a variable
wb.document.getElementById("usernameField").value := Loginname
wb.document.getElementById("passwordField").value := Password

IEGet(Name="")        ;Retrieve pointer to existing IE window/tab
{
    IfEqual, Name,, WinGetTitle, Name, ahk_class IEFrame
        Name := ( Name="New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer" ) ? "about:Tabs"
        : RegExReplace( Name, " - (Windows|Microsoft) Internet Explorer" )
    For wb in ComObjCreate( "Shell.Application" ).Windows
        If ( wb.LocationName = Name ) && InStr( wb.FullName, "iexplore.exe" )
            Return wb
} ;written by Jethrow
```

but i cant seem to figure out how to invoke the login submit form this

```
        <form id="login" action="javascript:submitCredentials();" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="control_box min_margin" id="UsernameBox">
            <label title="User Name" for="usernameField" message="FND_SSO_USER_NAME">User Name</label>
            <input name="usernameField" tabindex="0" class="inp" id="usernameField" type="text" value="" message="FND_SSO_USER_NAME">

        </div>

                <div class="control_box min_margin" id="logoutLink" style="display: none;"><a name="logout" tabindex="0" title="Not ?  Log Out" onclick="confirmLogout()" message="FND_SSO_NOTSAME_USER">Not ?  Log Out</a></div>
        <div class="control_box min_margin">
            <label title="Password" for="passwordField" message="FND_SSO_PASSWORD">Password</label>
            <input name="passwordField" tabindex="0" class="inp" id="passwordField" type="password" value="" message="FND_SSO_PASSWORD">
        </div>
        </form>
        <div class="control_box center" id="ButtonBox">

            <button tabindex="0" class="OraButton left" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px;" onclick="submitCredentials()" message="FND_SSO_LOGIN">Login</button>
            <button tabindex="0" class="OraButton right" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px;" onclick="handleCancel()" message="FND_SSO_CANCEL">Cancel</button>
        </div>
```

so far the script fills in the username and password but then just stops
I would like it to submit the username and password,

if any one can help i would be so grateful, i have spent hours going in circles and have run out of things i know how to try

thanks in advance

Edit:
Thanks to the link provided by Evan Elrod i was able to find "wb.document.getElementsByTagName( "form" ).Submit()" which has made the code work for me, (https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=21091)

Comment: Take a look at this thread. I think your solution may be in it. https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=21091

Comment: Thank you Evan Elrod i was able to find, wb.document.getElementsByTagName( "form" )[1].Submit(), and it worked like a charm